# How to get the highest number and corresponding name in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, promise, fetch

I have a table that pulls in data from an API. Now I want to parse the data and get the tallest height and the name that goes with it. the data is coming from https://swapi.co/api/species/1/ Here is the code that works and pulls in the data into a table:

```
const url = 'https://swapi.co/api/species/1/';
 function fetchData(url) {
   return fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json());
 }

   function constructTableRow(data) {
     const row = document.createElement('tr');
     const { name, height, mass, hair_color } = data;
     row.appendChild(constructElement('td', name))
     row.appendChild(constructElement('td', height))
     row.appendChild(constructElement('td', mass))
     row.appendChild(constructElement('td', hair_color))
     return row;
 }

    const swTable = document.getElementById('sw-table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
   fetchData(url).then(data =>
   data.people.forEach(personUrl =>
   fetchData(personUrl).then(result => {
     const row = constructTableRow(result);
     swTable.appendChild(row);
   })
 )
);
```

Here is the problem code:

```
   const getAvgHeight = async url =>
  fetch(url)
   .then(r => r.json())
   .then(
       async data =>
       (await Promise.all( 
        data.people.map( personUrl => 
           fetch(personUrl) 
             .then(r => r.json())
             .then(person => parseInt(person.height)) 
         )
       // filter out unkwown
      )).filter(height => !isNaN(height)) 
   )
   const maxHeight = height.Math.max(height)
  .then(heights => heights(maxHeight)); 
 getAvgHeight("https://swapi.co/api/species/1/").then(result => 
 document.getElementById('sw-tall').innerHTML = result.toFixed(2));
```

When I run this code I get the error: `height is not defined`

What's missing?

Answer (score 1):

I see you re-used the code for average mass from the previous question/answer (getting average mass of said persons). That makes sense, the process is actually quite similar, and you're almost there. :)

Your function is named `getAvgHeight`, but it seems to try to get the maximum height actually, so i assume this is what you intended.

The problem mostly lies in:

```
const maxHeight = height.Math.max(height)
```

First, `height` is not defined in that context, it was used just inside the `Promise.all(…)` during fetching person data.

Second, even if you had height(s) defined, `Math.max` doesn't work like this:

```
[202, 177, 165].Math.max() // nope, arrays don't have Math at all
Math.max([202, 177, 165]) // this would make sense, sort of… but Math.max expects the actual numbers, not an array of them, and it returns NaN (because an array is not a number)
Math.max(202, 177, 165) // this works, returns 202
Math.max(...[202, 177, 165]) // this would also work, read more about it here if you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
```

You probably want to read docs for `Math.max`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

So, you can get the biggest number (height) like this, but you lost the associated name in the process.

It would be better to sort the people in array by their height, and then get the first (= highest) one. Or even all of them, sorted:

```js
const getPersonsByHeight = async url =>
  fetch(url)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(
      async data =>
        (await Promise.all(
          data.people.map(personUrl =>
            fetch(personUrl)
              .then(r => r.json())
              .then(person => ({
                // keep the name:
                name: person.name,
                // and height converted to integer:
                height: parseInt(person.height)
              })) // => { "name": "Darth Vader", "height": 202 }
          )
        ))
          .filter(person => !isNaN(person.height))
          // sort array by person.height:
          .sort((personA, personB) => personB.height - personA.height)
          // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
    );
    
    /* ->
    [
      {
        "name": "Darth Vader",
        "height": 202
      },
      {
        "name": "Qui-Gon Jinn",
        "height": 193
      },
      {
        "name": "Dooku",
        "height": 193
      },
      …
    ]
    */

getPersonsByHeight("https://swapi.co/api/species/1/").then(people =>{
  console.log(`highest: ${people[0].name}`); // people[0] is the first person, people[1] the second etc.
  console.log('height chart using forEach:');
  people.forEach((person, index) => console.log(`${index + 1}. ${person.name}, ${person.height} cm`))
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying several different fetches. I also want the most frequent hair color, but I think that one would have to be a function inside the fetch.

Comment: That would be a bit more tricky, this might help: https://codepen.io/emissary/pen/WryEve?editors=0012

Comment: Awesome thanks. Also, would it be tricky to sort names by the last name alphabetically?

Comment: No, but you'd have to think about some edge cases. Some of them have just a single-word name ("Dooku"), some have two words, some three. It would be the same code as above, just the `.sort(…)` function would be different. Hint: you can split names into array with `.split` like this: `"Darth Vader".split(" ") // -> ["Darth", "Vader"]`. Then just get the first letter of the last name and sort by it.

Comment: See this if you get lost in in: https://vgy.me/S0C8hb.png . The `condition ? foo : bar` thing used there is called a ternary operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: couldn't I just add a `result.name.split` to this piece of code the displays the names and attributes?
      const swTable = document.getElementById('sw-table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        fetchData(url).then(data =>
        data.people.forEach(personUrl =>
          fetchData(personUrl).then(result => {
            const row = constructTableRow(result);
            swTable.appendChild(row);
          })
        )
      );

Comment: Yes, of course, you could just sort it before displaying. Depends on other things you need to do with it.